# HQL: Trouble with trivial select with aggregate function

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have very simple data model like this:

```
create table Company (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    street varchar(50)
)

create table Person (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    id_company int foreign key references Company
)
```

corresponding java classes like this:

```
class Company {
    int id;
    String name, street;
    List<Person> employees;
    // getters, setters, ctor
}

class Person {
    int id;
    String name, surname;
    Company employer;
    // getters, setters, ctor
}
```

Now, I 'd like to select Company with most employees with **HQL**. I don't know how, here's my rubbish pseudo attempt that doesn't work:

```
from Company c having max(c.employees);
```

Comment: see my updated answer below, got it working

Comment: update answer again, returns the company id having the most employees in HQL

Comment: updated again, hopefully last update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: this worked for me - to get company id and employee count

```
select c.id, max(c.employees.size) from Company c
```

To get the company object:

```
from Company comp
where comp.employees.size = (
  select max(c.employees.size) from Company c
)
```

If you don't have the hibernate plugin for eclipse yet install it it's great for this as it also displays the generated sql so you can optimize your hql, see http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html.

Just thought of something, what happens if two companies CompA and CompB both have the highest number of employees, say 50, i.e. all other companies have less than 50, do you care which company id you get back? Are you more interested in the number 50 or the company id?

Comment: You would add property to Employee class, not to Company in your code sample. Nevertheless, I hope there is better solution than adding ambiguous property to Company class :/

Comment: This isn't valid HQL, you can't have a HAVING without a GROUP BY.

Comment: @Jason Day - you're right, I fixed it, tested it this time, it works :)

Comment: select c, max(c.employees.size) from Company c. This actually also selects the company. Now, how to mow max(...) to the "where" clause? We're almost there :)

Comment: you just want the company id?

Comment: no problem, glad i got it working, also do play around with the jboss hibernate plugin for eclipse

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial, actually.  I can't think of a way to do what you want with a single query, but you can do it with two queries using something like this:

```
String hql = "select p.employer.id, count(*) from Person p group by p.employer.id order by count(*) desc";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setMaxResults(1);
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
Object[] oa = list.get(0);
Integer companyId = oa[0];
Company company = session.get(Company.class, companyId);
```

The above code assumes that there is only one Company that has the most employees.  It is possible of course for multiple companies to have the same number of employees which also happen to be the maximum.

Comment: First of all, thanx for your effort. This might work but isn't this too complex? I might as well just select all Companies and iterate thru them in Java code, that would be even more straightforward, or? :)

Comment: Nope, it's actually quite good :) I like more eon's query but you have rest correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select company from Company company order by company.employees.size
```

In code you retrieve only the first element.

```
query.setMaxResult(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Hibernate [chapter on HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation), specifically the aggregate function section:

`select avg(cat.weight), sum(cat.weight), max(cat.weight), count(cat)
from Cat cat`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helpful since it doesn't mention aggreagting with collections as properties (c.employees) in my case.